# How to get a connection for the whole servlet?

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, jdbc, oracle11g

I have connected to my database (Oracle 11g) from my servlet using:

```
Class.forName(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver);

Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:admin","username","password");
```

I would like to have the same connection for any other servlets that i create!

suppose a servlet named a.java makes a connection to the database. within the same package we have another servlet b.java

how do i get the value of the connection reference of a.java in b.java?

Comment: Remember that SO is not general tutorial and somebody-do-my-homework site. So what is your specific problem? Do you get any error messages or else? You have posted a lot of code, please read [this section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in Help Center. If you follow that guidelines your question more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have the same connection for any other servlets that i create!

No you wouldn't. You would hate it. You don't even want the same connection throughout a servlet, let alone across all servlets in a webapp. You need a new connection per transaction. Otherwise you will have to synchronize all accesses to it and your webapp will grind to a halt unless there is only one client, in which case it's all hardly worth the trouble.

Use a connection pool.

Comment: Went & did it anyway-- Made a context listener!
And I hate it!

When i was running the web app, all of a sudden the app crashed as number of gateways to the result set exceeded! I had to change everything from the beginning! Nightmare!

I still do not know what a connection pool is but I will research it once I finish this project!

Thanks!

Comment: One of the things that has always baffled me is why people post questions in places like this when they have no intention of taking the slightest notice of any of the answers they are given. You have just wasted a substantial amount of your own time and your employer's money on a task that you had already been told was completely and utterly futile. Perhaps next time you will listen to what you're told.

Comment: I am sorry that I wasted your time. But that was the way it was taught to us: to give a connection to database in the deployment descriptor using context listener.

Comment: Sorry But I did not know what a connection pool was and project date was close. Sometimes trainers that don't know best practices to code pass on their inaccurate knowledge to students. Our instructor taught us to code JSP in Scriplets! Which you know is a bad practice that backfires! The instructor was the one that told me to make a context listener in deployment descriptor for database connectivity--which backfired! Tell me: do you think three weeks of JAVA and a person can build an entire e-shopping website? But I had to build it on a very puny level of knowledge! That's why I turned to SO!